# DLL using JNI Java classes

Tags: java, c++, dll, java-native-interface

I'm writing a C++ dll (file extension in Visual Studio is .cpp but the code is C) which uses JNI for loading and calling instance methods of some Java classes. As a result my project is made up by C++ source and header files plus some Java class files (the class files for the Java objects used through JNI). I would like to create a single dll library including also the Java class files "in a single bundle". Is it possible to put both the C and Java files into the dll?

Comment: You could certainly take some .class files, package them into one or more JARs and include them as data in a DLL. You could even launch the JVM used for running the Java bytecode from within your DLL. I'm not entirely sure about whether you'd be able to get the JVM to load your classes without (temporarily) writing them to disk, though. I'll let someone with more knowledge about the JVM answer that.

Comment: What if I add the class files as "external resources"? (I'm using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010).

Comment: Sounds doable as long as you set up the classpath for the JVM correctly. I won't swear on it since it isn't something I've tried.

Comment: You can definitely put your compiled *.class files or a single jar into the DLL resource section. However you have to provide a custom class loader so that JVM could find those classes from DLL resources. Some JNI glue is required, but absolutely doable.

Comment: The ZIP file format allows for arbitrary "junk" data on the front of a zip file (but not on the end), so one option might be to simply put the class files into a JAR, concatenate that onto the end of the DLL and then use the path to the DLL _itself_ as the classpath for the JVM.

Comment: That'd be an interesting test.

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly possible, though not necessarily intuitive. I haven't tested this but I would imagine it would work easily if you knew what you were doing.

First off, you're going to need a way to package the class file's binary into the native binary you own, and then of course be able to seamlessly read that chunk at any point in time. How you achieve this is up to you, there is no real *'right way'* to do it.

That being said, if you can get a handle to the memory where the .class file's data resides (after loading the DLL) and pass it to Java as a `byte[]` or `ByteBuffer`, you'd then want to use any one of `ClassLoader`'s `defineClass` overloads along with a call to `findLoadedClass` and then finally `loadClass`.

This would allow you to load in a class from virtually any data source. As I mentioned before, how you store/retrieve the native data for the class is up to you.

Comment: Do you think is it possible to compile .java and .class files with GCJ generating object files and then let the linker put together all the object files into a dll? I mean using GCJ to generate native binary instead of bytecode.

Comment: Possibly, though if you're using GCJ to compile Java bytecode to native bytecode, I'm not sure if the JVM will recognize it and be able to load it in using `defineClass`; I think it expects Java bytecode, though I could be completely wrong.

Personally, I'd write a custom packager for it, or try to find a packer that can put auxiliary files into a binary.